# What is the relation between a $D_2$-brane and an $M2$-brane?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, branes, supergravity

I am only familiar with the concept of a $D_2$-brane from a first course in String theory. I would like to learn, at least on a conceptual level, what an $M2$-brane is and what is its relation to the $D_2$-brane.

What I (think I) know: they are both extended (2D) objects in higher dimensional spacetimes, and I suppose that since the $M$ in $M2$-brane refers to $M$-theory, the $M2$-brane exists in supersymmetric theories, in contrast to the $D_2$-brane which also exists in non-supersymmetric string theory.

Comment: Type IIA string theory is M theory with 11th dimension compactified. D2 brane is M2 brane that is not wrapped around that compact dimension.

Comment: @MitchellPorter thanks for the comment. So, where does SUSY come into play then?

Comment: There is no particular relationship. Both M-theory and Type IIA string theory are supersymmetric in their uncompactified forms, but can lose some or all of that supersymmetry when compactified or otherwise modified.